# JavaScript not able to Manipulate value and expiry date of cookie

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, cookie

I have to set a **cookie** in magento, say **current_city** in OPC. I have set the same via Magento in **built cookie function**.

```
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('current_city',$city);
```

I wanted to modify the **value and expiry** of the cookie in front end when the city value is changed from a dropdown.

I tried to use following magento js function to update the cookie.

```
Mage.Cookies.set('current_city',city,365*24*3600*1000);
```

But the cookie is not getting updated or deleted.

**What might be the issue?**

Thanks.!